# How to efficiently check if a string contains at least one element from two lists

Tags: python

I have two lists and a list of sentences as follows.

```
list1 = ['data mining', 'data sources', 'data']
list2 = ['neural networks', 'deep learning', 'machine learning']

sentences = ["mining data using neural networks has become a trend", "data mining is easy with python", "machine learning is my favorite", "data mining and machine learning are awesome", "data sources and data can been used for deep learning purposes", "data, deep learning and neural networks"]
```

I want to pick sentences that have elements from both `list1` and `list2`. i.e. the output should be;

```
["mining data using neural networks has become a trend", "data mining and machine learning are awesome", "data sources and data can been used for deep learning purposes", "data, deep learning and neural networks"]
```

My current code is as follows.

```
for sentence in sentences:
    for terms in list1:
        for words in list2:
           if terms in sentence:
               if words in sentence:
                     print(sentence)
```

However, the code is O(n^3) and not very efficient. Is there any efficient way of doing this in python?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: That about _maximizes_ your complexity / runtime.. see the answer below (sets) for a better approach

Comment: It may not really reduce theoretical complexity but an approach can be regular expressions. Check if sentence matches a regular expression pattern created by `'|'.join(list1)` (escaping omitted for clarity) then you know that the sentence contains at least one item of `list1`. Then same for `list2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can utilise the short circuiting of `all` and `any` for an improvement in performance:

```
list1 = ['data mining', 'data sources', 'data']
list2 = ['neural networks', 'deep learning', 'machine learning']
sentences = ["mining data using neural networks has become a trend", "data mining is easy with python", "machine learning is my favorite", "data mining and machine learning are awesome", "data sources and data can been used for deep learning purposes", "data, deep learning and neural networks"]

for sentence in sentences:
    if all(any(term in sentence for term in lst) for lst in (list1, list2)):
        print(sentence)
```

Answer (score 4):

Sets are going to be more efficient to look through than lists. You can check the intersection (`&`) of each sentence with the two "lists" rather than using your nested loops *if* you are looking for sentences that contain *single* words from *both* lists:

```
list1 = set(list1)
list2 = set(list2)
[sentence for sentence in set(sentences.split()) if sentence & list1 & list2]
```

---

However, since it seems your lists contain *phrases* (or sequence of words), it might be hard to avoid using multiple loops. You can at least break from or continue a loop if you find or don't find a match. There's also no need to nest within each other the loops for the two lists that you are matching to.

```
result = []
for sentence in sentences:
    for word in list1:
        if word in sentence:
            break
    else:
        continue
    for word in list2:
        if word in sentence:
            break
    else:
        continue
    result.append(sentence)
```

Result:

```
['mining data using neural networks has become a trend',
 'data mining and machine learning are awesome',
 'data sources and data can been used for deep learning purposes',
 'data, deep learning and neural networks']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Just wondering why I am getting this error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'set'`

Comment: How does the logic of this answer work? For example, `bool({1,2,3} & {1,2} & {3})` returns `False`.

Comment: Set operations won't help here because a sentence string may contain a list item as substring. This can't be tested with set operations.

Comment: @busybear Your new solution does not work. I get only `['mining data using neural networks has become a trend']`.

Comment: @Tomothy32 Ahh you're right. I had a `break` when I needed a `continue`.

Comment: `matches` is now superfluous because `result.append` can only be reached if  no `continue` happened before.

Comment: Good catch. The `continue` was a thought after writing everything else.

Answer (score 2):

Try to reduce loops like this:

```
list1 = ['data mining', 'data sources', 'data']
list2 = ['neural networks', 'deep learning', 'machine learning']

sentences = ["mining data using neural networks has become a trend", "data mining is easy with python", "machine learning is my favorite", "data mining and machine learning are awesome", "data sources and data can been used for deep learning purposes", "data, deep learning and neural networks"]

matches_list_1 = set()
matches_list_2 = set()

for index, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    for terms in list1:
        if terms in sentence:
            matches_list_1.add(index)
    for terms in list2:
        if terms in sentence:
            matches_list_2.add(index)

for index in (matches_list_1 & matches_list_2):
    print(sentences[index])
```